# From Javafile to SQL query - Minecraft plugin

Tags: java, sql, minecraft, translate

as i am working on a minecraft server some plugin does not make a certain table itself.
For who is interested: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/craftconomy.2395/

But in the github files i found the java script where it does generate the needed table.

```
public final String createTableMySQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + getPrefix() + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        "  `" + BALANCE_FIELD + "` double DEFAULT NULL," +
        "  `" + WORLD_NAME_FIELD + "` varchar(255)," +
        "  `username_id` int(11)," +
        "  `" + CURRENCY_FIELD + "` varchar(50)," +
        "  PRIMARY KEY (" + WORLD_NAME_FIELD + ", username_id, currency_id)," +
        "  CONSTRAINT `"+getPrefix()+"fk_balance_account`" +
        "    FOREIGN KEY (username_id)" +
        "    REFERENCES " + getPrefix() + AccountTable.TABLE_NAME + "(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE," +
        "  CONSTRAINT `"+getPrefix()+"fk_balance_currency`" +
        "    FOREIGN KEY (" + CURRENCY_FIELD + ")" +
        "    REFERENCES " + getPrefix() + CurrencyTable.TABLE_NAME +"(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE" +
        ") ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;";
```

Could someone help me to make a SQL query out of this, which just can be dropped into PHPMyadmin?
Thanks already for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it myself, no reason for reaction anymore.